# Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead)

Tags: php, post, netbeans

Перелазил уже и английский stackoverflow, но проблему не удалось устранить. А заключается она вот в чем: сначала была ошибка, все советовали заменить `$_POST` на `filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name")`.
 Но теперь, после компиляции, на странице отображается ошибка:

> Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null
>   !== func()" instead)

```
<?php

if(isset( filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name") )){
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name" == "admin") && filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pass' == 'admin')){

 header("Location:newpage.php");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Что не понятного в ошибке? Вы пытаетесь проверить функцию на isset...

Comment: isset предназначена для проверки переменных на существование.

Comment: после header лучше использовать exit;

Answer (score 2):

Так всё же написано. И чем заменить тоже написано. Вольный перевод, но технический английский вам научиться понимать надо обязательно:

> невозможно использовать isset для результата функции. Вы можете использовать null !== func() вместо этого

Конструкция языка `isset` (не функция! Это языковая конструкция, потому и имеет своё поведение) не может проверять результат функции. Поскольку функция что-то возвращает всегда (в реалиях PHP даже return; вернёт неявно null), а помимо проверки переменной на существование, isset так же проверяет на равенство null, поэтому и предлагается сравнить результат функции с null.